# Compare String Values in 2 Worksheets, if they match, then I want to insert values from two columns in the second worksheet into the first worksheet

Tags: excel, vba

I am very new to VBA and have been learning off of Youtube and StackOverflow for the last 1.5 months, so forgive me for my ignorance. I have two worksheets, one contains all personnel records (sheet1), the other contains temporary personnel records (sheet2). I want to take the PositionID number from sheet2 and compare with the PositionID number from sheet1. If they match, then I want to enter the First and Last name of the employee in that PositionID from sheet2 into the corresponding columns in sheet1.

Sheet1 (Has about 6000 records)

| PosID | Lname |
| --- | --- |
| 12345 |  |
| 23456 |  |
| 34567 |  |

Sheet2 (Has about 25 records and is updated Monthly)

| PosID | Lname |
| --- | --- |
| 12345 | Smith |
| 23456 | Johnson |
| 34567 | Watts |

I tried manipulating the script from a code that removed rows on the criteria that if the PosID, Lname, and Fname from sheet2 matched the same fields in sheet1, then delete the row from sheet1.

I get the following error message:

Run-time error '1004':

Method 'Range' of object'_Global' failed on this line ----lname = Range(c2row, 1) And fname = Range(c2row, 2)

```
Sub PosID_Insert()

Dim ws1 As Worksheet
Dim ws2 As Worksheet
Dim c1row As Long
Dim c2row As Long
Dim c2totalrows As Long
Dim posID As String
Dim lname As String
Dim fname As String

Set ws1 = Worksheets("Sheet1")
Set ws2 = Worksheets("Sheet2")
ws2.Activate
c2totalrows = Application.CountA(Range("A:A"))
c1row = 2

Do While ws1.Cells(c1row, 1).Value <> ""
posID= ws1.Cells(c1row, 1).Value
lname = ws1.Cells(c1row, 8).Value
fname = ws1.Cells(c1row, 9).Value

    For c2row = 2 To c2totalrows
        If posID= Cells(c2row, 5).Value Then
        lname = Range(c2row, 1) And fname = Range(c2row, 2)
    Exit For
        End If

Loop


End Sub
```

Comment: Your `End If` should be above the `Exit For`.

Comment: I corrected this and ran it but it seems to either be a long process because it crashes Excel or the code is not optimal.

Answer (score 0):

assuming values in both sheets are in column A-B-C starting at row 2

```
Sub CopyValues()

Dim s1arr(), s2arr()
Dim last1 As Long, last2 As Long, i As Long, k As Long

last1 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(Rows.Count,"A").End(xlUp).Row
last2 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(Rows.Count,"E").End(xlUp).Row

s1arr() = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A2:I" & last1).Value
s2arr() = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("A2:E" & last2).Value

For i = 1 To UBound(s1arr)
    For k = 1 To UBound(s2arr)
        If s1arr(i, 1) = s2arr(k, 5) Then
            s1arr(i, 9) = s2arr(k, 2)
            s1arr(i, 8) = s2arr(k, 1)
        End If
    Next k
Next i

ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A2:I" & last1).Value = s1arr

End Sub
```

sheet2

[image]

sheet1

[image]

Comment: The fields are not in the same location on both sheets. One has 20 plus columns the other has 10.

Comment: @JorgeSM in sheet1 where is the column for POSID,Fname,Lname? in sheet2 where is the column of POSID,Fname,Lname?

Comment: Sheet 1 Table: Pos ID (Column A), Last Name (Column H), First Name (Column I)
Sheet 2 Table: Pos ID (Column E), Last Name (Column A), First Name (Column B)

Comment: @JorgeSM try updated code above

Comment: Unfortunately, the script didn't work. It ran with no issues but the expected changes were not made.

Comment: @JorgeSM from my testing it works updated post above to show sample data, the code will copy last and first name from sheet 2 to sheet 1